# What are some example pledges to join a court in Changeling: The Lost?

Tags: changeling-the-lost

I scoured the CtL book for examples but couldn't find any.  If there *are* any I'd love a page number.  Otherwise, if you have a link to a wiki with them I'd appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pledge you are looking for is called Commendation and is found on **page 189** of the core Changeling book.

Page 181 of the Changeling core book has the Vassalage boon and a side panel that explains that freeholds come in many shapes and sizes but the ones that are enforced by the Wyrd are usually pledges of loyalty sworn to an anointed ruler.

If you are interested in an example of one that is in play after many revisions and years of play, feel free to look at the one for a game that I'm a part of.

Freehold: http://camarilla.org.au/wiki/index.php?title=Sydney_Lost_Freehold

Pledges: http://camarilla.org.au/wiki/index.php?title=Sydney_Lost_Law

Comment: Interesting.  I figured you'd join the freehold with one pledge and then join a specific court with another.

Comment: See, what confuses me is that on page 45 of CtL it says: "Joining a Court involves a pledge on the part of the changeling, and the changeling's Wyrd supports the pledge."  I mean, I guess joining the freehold could also be joining the court, but... it just doesn't seem that way?

Comment: I don't remember seeing a pledge for joining a Court because it doesn't actually take up a pledge "slot" as far as I'm aware.
The system for benefits and penalties for being part of a Court are completely different to how pledges are handled so there may not be a pledge specifically for joining a Court.

Comment: Ok, so like, you just... "I pledge to join the Winter Court" or something like that, after you've joined the Freehold I guess.